# Contact Builder and Data Extensions won't render in Developer Account

Tags: marketing-cloud, developer-edition, contactbuilder

Has anyone had issues with Contact Builder and/or Data Extensions showing in a Developer Account. [image: Error Received when clicking on Contact Builder]